# Is it possible for me to know if I have cleaned up properly in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have code that looks something like,

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char** someArray = NULL;
size_t numberOfEntriesInArray = 0;
void addToArray(char* someString){
  someArray = realloc(someArray, (numberOfEntriesInArray+1) * sizeof(char*));
  someArray[numberOfEntriesInArray] = malloc( (strlen(someString) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
  strcpy(someArray[numberOfEntriesInArray], someString);
  numberOfEntriesInArray++;
}
void deleteSomeArray(){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfEntriesInArray; i++){
    free(someArray[i]);
  }
  free(someArray);
}
int main(){
  addToArray( .. );
  ..
  deleteSomeArray();
}
```

Is there a way I can know `deleteSomeArray` has worked properly?
i.e. Is there a way to check if there is still more memory that needs to be freed?

P.S.

If I leak memory in my program, is the memory automatically freed when my program dies? If not, is there a way to get at the leaked memory?

Comment: Concerning the P.S., on all common platforms, the OS reclaims the memory when the program exits, so no leak survives its program.

Comment: If the question is "have I lost a pointer, and forgotton to free it?" Valgrind is a sledge hammer to crack a nut. Just look a my answer. As we say in the UK "Simples"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if there is still more memory that needs to be freed?

Use a [memory debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger).  If you are working in Linux (or similar), then the canonical example is [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).

> If I leak memory in my program, is the memory automatically freed when my program dies?

On most modern OSes, yes, the OS reclaims all memory when a process terminates.  But you shouldn't treat this as an excuse for leaking memory!

Comment: That's not a good excuse for leaking a *lot* of memory, but it's good reason not to worry overmuch about leaking a small, bounded amount of memory (e.g. in a singleton class, or a framework with fixed heap-memory overhead, or whatnot).

Comment: @ruakh: Hmm, I disagree, for at least two reasons.  (1) things that are initially "global" in your design have a habit of becoming less so in the future (things get refactored into libraries etc.)  (2) it tends to clutter the output of e.g. Valgrind with noise (although this can be mitigated with a suppression file).

Comment: It can be a good excuse for leaking a lot of memory too. E.g. in short lived toolchain processes. I'd rather have a compiler reach 200 megs of virtual memory than to segfault because it freed something it should not have.

Comment: @Kaz: Again, hmm.  Your argument seems to be "I might make a mistake freeing, so I won't bother!".  But those mistakes are exactly what something Valgrind is there to help you find.

Comment: @ruakh: If everyone took attitude that a few memory leaks are acceptable, than when you have 60+ developers working on the source code, and they all don't give a crap about memory leaks (yes it happens) then you have a recipe for crappy code.

Comment: @CJohnson: You need a lot less than 60 for that to occur!

Comment: @CJohnson: If you have 60+ developers creating singleton objects and pervasive frameworks in a single application, then you have a recipe for crappy code no matter what they do or don't give a crap about. (And I didn't say "a few memory leaks are acceptable". The number of memory leaks is irrelevant: a million memory leaks are acceptable if you need all of those allocations for the entire duration of the program and the only question is whether to clean them up at the end of `main`. Conversely, even a single memory leak can be a problem if it's genuinely a memory leak.)

Comment: Though I also agree with Oli. It's good to use Valgrind when you're coding, and have the policy that Valgrind output is quiet. Cleaning everything up is a waste of cycles though; it can considerably prolong the shut down of a program. So it's good to have a flag for this. You can have the "spic-and-span" cleanup enabled when you're running your regression test suite but maybe not in deployed code.

Comment: @ruakh: However, as an addendum, I do agree that on the list of priorities on a time-critical project, true leaks are much higher up than unfreed memory at termination.

Comment: Linux kernel modules often have singleton objects in them, and that's more than 60 developers.

Comment: Valgrind, though very good, is no panacea. Since it is a run-time tool, it will not find any bug that your test cases do not actually step on. If `problematic_function` frees a pointer twice, but the test coverage is such that `problematic_function` is never called ... oops.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: In that case, I think we agree in substance: we both feel that that's not necessarily a high priority to clean up memory at termination, but we both feel that it's better to do so than not to.

Comment: I disagree. Firefox is the classic example of it being worse to free memory at termination, and the classic example of why the CS definition of memory leak is wrong. It allocates and holds onto huge amounts of memory as long as its running (with no way to reduce memory usage short of restarting) -- that's the real definition of a memory leak. And then at exit, it walks and frees hundreds of megs (or more) of memory that hasn't been touched in days and that was swapped out to disk, thereby thrashing the disk and evicting other programs' actually-useful pages from the page cache.

Comment: In short, best practice is to free actually-unneeded memory as soon as it's not going to be needed. And for the cases where memory really can't be freed until program termination, never free it.

Answer (score 1):

> If I leak memory in my program, is the memory automatically freed when
>   my program dies?

All modern Operating Systems (Linux, Windows OS X, ...Android, ... ) will clear up when a program (a process) dies.

What Operating System are you using?  There are still a few systems which do not, but you'll need to tell us what OS you are using to help.

---

> Is there a way I can know deleteSomeArray has worked properly? i.e. Is
>   there a way to check if there is still more memory that needs to be
>   freed?

There are a bunch of ways to find this out. There are commercial products which do it, but I assume you don't want one of those. Valgrind too.

Don't waste your time with valgrind until you know you have a problem. If all you want to know if 'have you lost a pointer, and not freed it?', and you are using Linux, or gcc, then you might look at [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc). This is a function which returns a struct which seems to tell you exactly how much memory malloc thinks it has free, and how much it is. Seems very simple, a few minutes effort.

Answer (score 1):

> If I leak memory in my program, is the memory automatically freed when my program dies? If not, is there a way to get at the leaked memory?

The OS kernel will automatically clean up all memory allocation, open files, network sockets, etc., that your process had open when it dies (regardless of the reason why the process was terminated).

The *only* exception is the shared memory, shared semaphores, and message queue IPC features provided for the System V IPC and the POSIX IPC mechanisms; see `ipc(5)`, `msgget(3)`, `semget(3)`, `shmget(3)` for details. (You would know if you're using these mechanisms; they are not very common. See the `ipcs(1)` utility for an easy way to see which shared memory segments, shared semaphores, and message queues are allocated on your system.)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use the function [`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you use [`_CrtSetDbgFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs.aspx) with the `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` flag, you can have the debugger automatically spit out all of your memory leaks with File and Line number information too. Those two links have much more information about the type of memory checking that can be done.

Answer (score -1):

You have to trust the free function, because you can't check if it is successful or not (you should have in mind it is always successfull otherwise your system have a big problem).

In recent OS when a program end, the allocated memorie is freed (even i there was a mem leak).

Your only way to test if you do not have a mem leak is by using a memory debugger like [Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oli-charlesworth) stated. Valgrind is a good choice.

When programming in C (or any langage that allow you to directly manage the memory), you have to ensure you free what you allocated, because the compiler won't tell you anything nor the program. Plus is does not exist any function in standard C to give you this info.